# Writing a binary file with lines more than 45 bytes: binascii.Error: At most 45 bytes at once

Tags: python, byte, binascii

My goal is to read a binary file and convert it to text. My code is :

```
def binary_to_text(self,file_name):
  open_file = open(file_name,"rb")
  with open("Binary2Text.txt", "a") as the_file:
    for line in open_file:
      the_file.write(binascii.b2a_uu(line))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
binascii.Error: At most 45 bytes at once
```

Is there a way to get around this, or is there another module I can use besides binascii? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `binascii.b2a_uu` method is meant to be a low-level function for performing uuencode, in which the algorithm encodes text input in 45-byte chunks, which is why there is a 45-byte chunk limit for input.

Unless you're trying to implement uuencode yourself, you should simply use the `uu.encode` method instead:

```
import uu    
def binary_to_text(self, file_name):
    with open("Binary2Text.txt", "a") as the_file:
        the_file.write(uu.encode(file_name))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Does uu.encode() also work if you pass in the path to the file? The binary files I need to convert are in another directory.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Yes `uu.encode` works for both a path name to a file and a file object.